# How to get current user categories in ModelForm?

Tags: django, django-models, django-views, django-forms

There is word study app. Currecnt user create own category with set of words. **The idea is to customize the list of options in the selection form for the current user.**

models.py

```
class ModelWords(models.Model):
    class Meta:
        verbose_name = 'Words'
        verbose_name_plural = 'Words'
    your_language_name = models.CharField(max_length=40)
    eng_name = models.CharField(max_length=40)
    cat = models.ForeignKey('ModelCatsWords', on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True)
    author = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL,on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    def __str__(self):
        return self.your_language_name

class ModelCatsWords(models.Model):
    class Meta:
        verbose_name = 'Categories'
        verbose_name_plural = 'Categories'
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100, db_index=True)
    author = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL,on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('category', kwargs={'cat_id': self.pk})
```

There is two forms. The first form to add words to it and there is a list of user categories to choose,  another form to add categories.

forms.py

```
class WordsFrom(forms.ModelForm):
    cat = forms.ChoiceField(choices=[], required=False, label="select cat")
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.request = kwargs.pop('request', None)
        super(WordsFrom, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.fields['cat'].choices = ModelCatsWords.objects.filter(author=self.request.user.id).values_list('name')
        for visible in self.visible_fields():
            visible.field.widget.attrs['placeholder'] = visible.field.label
    class Meta:
        model = ModelWords
        fields =  ['your_language_name', 'eng_name','cat']
        labels = {
            'your_language_name' : 'word on your language',
            'eng_name' : 'word on english',
            'cat' : 'categorie'
        }

class ModelCatsWordsForm(forms.ModelForm):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.fields['name'].widget.attrs['placeholder'] = 'categorie'
    class Meta:
        model = ModelCatsWords
        fields = ['name']
        labels = {
            'name': 'Categorie'
        }
```

There is views.py

```
class WordsFormView(View):

    def get(self,request):
        form_for_word = WordsFrom(request=request)
        form_for_categorie = ModelCatsWordsForm()

        return render(request,'app/appendwords.html',context={'form':form_for_word,'form_for_categorie':form_for_categorie})
```

please, help with some code example

Comment: Can you [edit] the question with the view(s) that use these forms?

Comment: But the idea is to make a (list) of words, and also create a category in the *same* request?

Comment: the idea is to customize the list of options in the selection form for the current user.

Answer (score 0):

You can already use this logic in `views.py`:

```
wordsform = WordsFrom() 

if self.request.user.is_authenticated:
    wordsform.fields['cat'].queryset = ModelCatsWords.objects.filter(author_id=self.request.user.id)
```